# Joomla : How to get variable passed by loadTemplate function

Tags: joomla

I am loading a template in my current php file using Joomla's loadTemplate function with passing the variables like below

```
<?php echo $this->loadTemplate('test', array('id' => '10')); ?>
```

While in the 'test.php', I am not getting this 'id' value. How can I get this?

Comment: it should be simply $id

Comment: have done this but not getting the value 10 for $id variable.. it gives blnak value

Comment: in fact i don't think you can pass data to this function, just the template name. The variables accessible to the parent template will just be accessible in the called template.

Comment: Where is your php file located. Is it inside Joomla component->views->tmp folder or outside Joomla folder. Give complete details.

Answer (score 1):

The `loadTemplate` function only has one argument, the name of the template (see the [API docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JViewLegacy.html#method_loadTemplate)).
What usually works for me is assigning the value to a variable on `$this`, for example `$this->myId = 10`.